# erlang typechecking

Tags: erlang, static-analysis

From what I understand there is no way of type-checking the messages send in erlang.

lets say i start a module with the following receive loop:

```
loop(State) ->
    receive 
    {insert, _} ->
        io:fwrite("insert\n",[]),
        loop(State);
    {view, _} ->
        io:fwrite("view\n", []),
        loop(State)
    after 10000 ->
        ok
    end.
```

There is no way for me to check what people are sending to the process, and no way to check for that its type safe?

Are there any easy work arrounds?

The one I have come up with is using functions in the module being called like :

```
send_insert(Message) ->
    whereis(my_event_handler) !  {insert, Message},
    ok.
```

this way at least I can add the `-spec send_insert(string()) -> ok.` spec to the module. now at least I have limited the error to my module.

Are there a more standard way of doing typechecking on messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [sheriff project](https://github.com/extend/sheriff) that solves your problem. You can use it for checking values against their type as defined through typespecs.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that having a function like `send_insert` in your module, that just sends a message to the process, is good practice not just for type checking.  If you need to change the message format some time in the future, you'll *know* that you only need to change that function and possibly its callers, which is easier to track down than finding all places that send a message of a certain format to some process (which may or may not be the process whose code you're refactoring). Also, since any callers will need to specify the module name, the code becomes a little more self-documenting; you'll know what process that message is supposed to go to.

(BTW, `whereis(my_event_handler) !  {insert, Message}` can be written as `my_event_handler ! {insert, Message}`.)

Comment: I don't know how I keep forgetting that the whereis call is unneeded

Answer (score 1):

Well, if what you need is just some basic type (and maybe range) checking, you can use [guards](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Erlang_Programming/guards):

```
receive 
    {insert, Message} when is_list(Message) ->
        io:fwrite("insert\n",[]),
        loop(State);
```

Unfortunately, because of some constraints (guards must be free of any side-effects, for example) there's no way to write your own guard functions.

Comment: Well.. Thats not really typechecking, there can be anything in that list :-)

Comment: But it had to be of list type, that's what I mean. )

Comment: I suggested guards in my answer too, but I see guards more as a complement to pattern matching, when defining functions of the same arity but with different behaviour depending on the argument type, as opposed to strict typechecking

Comment: I generally agree with what's said in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2625883/1229023). In that topic it was also said guards can be faster overall, but I'd like to verify this on my own environment.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, "**-spec**" is only for documentation purposes and will not check your types at runtime.

As you correctly say, there's no typechecking per se, but you can have a mix of pattern matching and [guards](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id79432) to make things fails. Nevertheless, this is all [defensive programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming), and you should just let it crash, and have a supervisor tree restart whatever needs to be restarted. The logs and crash reports should give you enough information to know what went wrong and act accordingly.